# jQuery - Can't set variables inside getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation

I am trying to create a weather app. First it prompts user to allow browser to get geo location, and then I am trying to get the weather from dark sky API using the coordinates. It is communicating with the API correctly since it updates the count, but I can not get the data to then update the HTML.

I have three separate tests, one that works correctly which updates HTML with the coordinates. But then I have two more tests inside the getJSON which do not work correctly; one which uses the JSON and the other which should update with a simple message.

The code looks like so..

```js
var lat;
var long;

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    long = position.coords.longitude;
    $("#trial").html("latitude: " + lat + "<br>longitude: " + long);

    var api = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/SECRETKEY/" + lat + "," + long;

    $.getJSON(api, function(json) {
      var zone = json.timezone;
      $("#data").html(zone);
      $("#lol").html("lolol");
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="trial"></div>
<div id="data"></div>
<div id="lol"></div>
```

I can also provide the key! Thanks a lot. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/josevarela24/5s9zhjsh/1/)

Comment: the json returns the array with timezone as one of the attributes. it never updates with the following line $("#data").html(zone); nor does $("#lol").html("lolol"); ever update. Since my API usage updates after each time running the code, it does reach the server, and so I do not think it fails. The fact that the "lol" never updates in the html is what gets me the most.

Comment: Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: method not going to the success call of ajax.
the end points are not CORS enabled.

Comment: I don't see an error, but nothing prints to console if I tried. And I keep seeing stuff around here about CORS but im brand new to this so I do not know what that is.